# How to create common objects for dialogs in QT

Tags: c++, qt

In my QT application im having three dialogs named as "one", "two", "three". i want to show and hide the dialogs "two" and "three" in dialog "one"(using buttons) and vice versa for all the dialogs.My question is how to create objects commonly for all dialogs (such as objects for the dialogs "one", "two", "three") , so that i can call any of the dialog in all other dialogs, i tried to create objects in main() function like,

```
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h"
#include "second.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  one *s = new one();
  two *d = new two();
  three *s = new three();
  return a.exec();
}
```

but i dont know how to call this pointer objects in another dialogs.Guide me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
one *d1 = new one();
two *d2 = new two();
three *d3 = new three();
d1.establish(d2, d3);
d2.establish(d1, d3);
d3.establish(d1, d2);
```

That is, inform each dialog of the pointers to the others, after you have created all of them.  Of course you could make a single function to encapsulate this logic if you want, or even a class to hold all three dialogs.

The `establish()` method above is just a hypothetical name; you'll have to implement it yourself.  For example:

```
void establish(one* d1, two* d2) {
  m_dlg1 = d1;
  m_dlg2 = d2;
}
```

If your dialogs only need generic QDialog pointers you could store those in a vector instead, if you want to be flexible in how many dialogs there are in total.

Comment: @john: your solution confusing me a litte bit , As per your suggestion i updated the code  in main function. now in my dialog "two" push button , i need to call dialog "one" (i created object "one" in my main function).how to call created object in the dialog "one". i created the method establish also in main() function . is that right? and what is the "m_dlg1" . can you please give me a little bit brief

Comment: @john: for better understanding , i ll update the code here how i implemented,                                                                                                    int main(int argc, char *argv[])

Comment: @sivanesan: `m_dlg1` is a member variable.  You'll need to add it to the appropriate classes (namely `two` and `three`).  The `establish` method is a class method, not a free function.

Comment: ok , now i got the idea , im implementing now , i ll check your answer after checking